# Yii2 - making migration file for procedures, functions and events

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, yii2, migration

I want to create one migration file, in which all code for creating tables, functions, procedures and events is stored. I export database and put it in the *$this->execute();*. Tables and keys, are migrated well with ***yii migrate***
, but procedures, functions and events have problems. On the first line. I copy same code in the phpmyadmin->sql and no errors displayed. What can be wrong? Is it possible to migrate stored proc, events and func?

```
[2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION*
```

Comment: If this is an error, an issue report in github would be more appropriate than a _question_. But it might not be, so if you post some more code someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` resolve the problem.